# Module federation remote loads it's own remoteEntry file

Tags: webpack, webpack-module-federation

I am using a basic module federation setup. One host and one remote.

When running a `remote` application (the one exposing components) in a sandbox mode, running without a host container just like a regular app, it loads its own remoteEntry.js

I've noticed that `remoteEntry.js` is being injected in the head.

Does anyone know what is the purpose of such behavior and how can I prevent that from happening?